# Confused how to calculate continous random variable with pdf that has a min

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem given was:

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function
>   $$f(x) = \dfrac 1 4 \min \left( 1, \dfrac 1 {x^2} \right)$$
>   Find $P(−2 \le X \le 4)$.

The $\min$ part has totally thrown me off, any suggestions or steps how to find $P$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac14 \quad &\text{if }\, |x|\leq 1,\\
\frac{1}{4}x^{-2}\quad&\text{if }\, |x|>1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: So I would integrate from -2 to 1, and 1 to 4?

Comment: Recall that $|x|\leq 1$ means that $-1\leq x\leq 1$. So you would have to split integration from -2 to 4 into three regions: from -2 to -1, from -1 to 1, and from 1 to 4.

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting on the right track now, thanks